# modifying Map of Maps in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary

What would be a proper way of working with a map of maps in Haskell?
Assuming that I want to have something like

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Key1   = String
type MyMap1 = M.Map Key1 Int
type Key    = String
type MyMap  = M.Map Key MyMap1
```

how am I supposed to implement the function which adds elements into the map?
The best I can think of is

```
addE :: Key -> Key1 -> Int -> MyMap -> MyMap
addE k k1 v = M.insertWith M.union k (M.singleton k1 v)
```

but `M.union` gives me *O(n)* complexity instead of expected *O(log n)*

Is there a better way to do this or another data structure that should be used instead?

Comment: Have you tried the `update` function?  Something like `addE k k1 v = M.update (Just . M.insert k1 v)` should work.

Comment: A map of maps is fine, but depending on what you actually do with it, you might want a `Map (Key,Key1) Int` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
addE :: Key -> Key1 -> Int -> MyMap -> MyMap
addE k k1 v = M.alter (Just . M.insert k1 v . fromMaybe M.empty) k
```